# Autohotkey : Navigate in Internet Explorer with remapped numpad keys

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I would like to set up an information terminal where colleagues can navigate through our intranet pages with a small number pad keyboard.

My goal is to remap keys with different shortcuts like e.g. "Alt-Left" so they can go back to the previous site. I tried to make it in a clean way, so the number pad is only remapped when the IE is open, visible and active:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class IEFrame
Numpad4::Send, {ALT LEFT}
#IfWinActive
```

The reason why I am asking for help is that the script is not working and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after some time, I figured it by myself:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class IEFrame
Numpad4::Send !{Left}
NumpadLeft::Send !{Left}

Numpad6::Send !{Right}
NumpadRight::Send !{Right}

Numpad1::Send !{Home}
NumpadEnd::Send !{Home}

Numpad3::Send {Volume_Down 2}
NumpadDown::Send {Volume_Down 2}

Numpad9::Send {Volume_Up 2}
NumpadUp::Send {Volume_Up 2}
#IfWinActive
```

My main problem was that the "Alt" key has to be placed as symbol "!" before the arrow keys. Everything will be working in IE only as intended.

If someone has a "cleaner" solution (with GoBack/GoForward-Methods) I would be grateful to read it.